# ng-model not changing on Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

In my application I have a div where the content depends on the value of a radio. The value is initialised in my controller when I click on a button and it is supposed to reset when I click on him again. My problem is that after the value is initialised I can change it using the radio but It won't change when I call the function.

My html code:

```
<div>  
    <div ng-if="pageType=='select'">
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="pageType" value="valueA">Value A</label>
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="pageType" value="valueB">Value B</label>   
    </div>
    <div ng-if="pageType=='valueA'">
        <div ng-controller="valueAController">
            <div ng-include="'views/valueA.html'"></div>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div ng-if="pageType=='valueB'">
        <div ng-controller="valueBController">
            <div ng-include="'views/value.html'"></div>
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>
```

My Controller js

```
$scope.resetValue= function () {
    $scope.pageType= "select";
}
```

Any idea of what is generating this error or maybe a workaround for it?

Comment: 1. Where is the rest of the controller's code? 2. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ng-if creates its own scope. So your ng-model updates the pageType of the ng-if's scope, not the pageType of your controller scope. Always have a dot in your ng-model. Initialize model.pageType in your controller, and use ng-model="model.pageType".

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the variable does initialise the first time I click on the button but won't change again after the value is set on the radio box. The rest of the code is actually big and no related but it is working without errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ngIf is creating an isolate scope, so it now has its own version of pageType. If you nest pageType another level on the $scope object it should work.

```
<div>  
    <div ng-if="pageType=='select'">
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="magicDot.pageType" value="valueA">Value A</label>
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="magicDot.pageType" value="valueB">Value B</label>   
    </div>
    <div ng-if="magicDot.pageType=='valueA'">
        <div ng-controller="valueAController">
            <div ng-include="'views/valueA.html'"></div>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div ng-if="magicDot.pageType=='valueB'">
        <div ng-controller="valueBController">
            <div ng-include="'views/value.html'"></div>
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.resetValue= function () {
    $scope.magicDot = {
      pageType: "select"
    };
}
```